# Get data from Database and set to jsp file

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp, jdbc

What should i do to get information from `database` and set them to `jsp` file. Should do this in my `controller` or maybe in jsp file?

What is simplest and fastest way?

Comment: Which technologies are you using ?

Comment: Spring Framework and MySQL

Comment: I am used to play with a framework, Struts 2. You might give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do it in the JSP file!  That's how things were done 15+ years ago before MVC frameworks and templates existed.  Use JSTL in your JSP to render the model's values.   Use your controller to build the model and supply it to the JSP (or other view template).

That's a broad answer based on a broad question.  Feel free to provide more specifics if that is not what you were asking.